# MySQL adding to query nullifies existing parts

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Database:

- xx_users (id, name, user_id, email, location)
- xx_questions (id, question, description, user_id)

Original code:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$arr= $friends['data'];
$friend_ids_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $friend) {
    $friend_ids_arr[] = $friend['id'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM xx_questions WHERE user_id IN (" . implode(',', $friend_ids_arr) . ") OR user_id = '$user' ORDER BY time DESC";
```

New code:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$arr= $friends['data'];
$friend_ids_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $friend) {
    $friend_ids_arr[] = $friend['id'];
}
    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM xx_questions q JOIN xx_users u ON
        q.user_id = u.user_id
    WHERE q.user_id IN (implode(',', $friend_ids_arr)) OR // STEP 1
        q.user_id = '$user' OR // STEP 2
        u.location = (SELECT location FROM xx_users WHERE user_id = $user) // STEP 3
    ORDER BY q .time DESC";

    $data = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        echo $row[id];
        }
```

I am trying to select questions from xx_questions (that have been posted by users) should any of three situations arise:

1. Those values where the poster's user_id matches that of one of the current user's friends (i.e. the poster and the user are friends)
2. Those values where the poster's user_id matches that of the user (i.e. the poster is the user)
3. Those values where the poster's location matches that of the current user (i.e. the poster and user are currently in the same city)

I had originally achieved steps 1 and 2, but when I add step 3, two things happen:

1. Step 1 stops working (i.e. only posts from the current user and people in the same city are returned)
2. The `$row[id]` echoed in the while loop is that of xx_users, not xx_questions. I've tried `$row[q.id]` but to no avail.

Any idea what's gone wrong?

Comment: **Heads up!** This is your obligatory notice that the next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Can you also show us the intermediary SQL you've used for step 2 before you get to the broken step 3?  Knowing what hasn't worked tends to be valuable.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I've added to and commented code.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  There was an implication that you have a step 1 query that works, a step 2 query that works, and that the current query you had listed was step 3, but it was busted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your seconds query your implode statement isnt outside the string.

```
"WHERE q.user_id IN (implode(',', $friend_ids_arr)) OR" // STEP 1
```

While php can add variable to a double quoted string (`$x = "test $test test"` $test will be changed to the value of $test) it can't escape functions. So this would return in

```
"WHERE q.user_id IN (implode(',', Array)) OR" // STEP 1
```

You should use:

```
"WHERE q.user_id IN (".implode(',', $friend_ids_arr).") OR" // STEP 1
```

And in the end you are using `SELECT *` and if both tables have an Id column, only one is returned. Its better to use `SELECT q.*` to get only the questions row or perhaps `SELECT q.*, u.location` to get the entire question row and the location from the user table.

I also checked your query and it should do what you want

```
$sql = "SELECT q.*, u.location
            FROM xx_questions q 
            JOIN xx_users u 
            ON q.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE q.user_id IN (".implode(',', $friend_ids_arr).") OR // STEP 1
            q.user_id = $user OR // STEP 2
            u.location = (SELECT location FROM xx_users WHERE user_id = $user) // STEP 3
            ORDER BY q.time DESC";
```

The only thing I changed is the `implode` and remove the '' around `$user`. That is incase the $user isnt actualy an integer but a string containing a number, but has some extra spaces appended (eg '1 ' instead of '1');

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm afraid this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Updated my awnser. What part of your question insnt solved yet? You are asking multiple things

Comment: Your updated answer solved part 2, thanks very much. However, I'm still having trouble with part 1.